# Using Scrapy itemloaders and XPath/CSS selector to extract data

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm using the `Scrapy` framework to crawl and scrape data from a url and I'm not sure whether it's better to extract the `value` `attribute` from a `progress bar` using `CSS selectors` or to extract the `text` data from a nested `div` & `span` tag using `XPath`.
This is the [URL](https://www.fragrantica.com/perfume/Xerjoff/Mefisto-Gentiluomo-52432.html)

---

This is the HTML code

```
<div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
    <div class="cell small-1 medium-1 large-1">
        <span class="vote-button-legend">12</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-6 medium-6 large-6" style="display: inline-flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
        <progress class="alert" max="297" value="12" style="color: crimson; cursor: pointer;"></progress>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the `inspector` I can verify with XPath selectors that I'm able to retrieve the text data:

```
$x('//div[@class="cell small-1 medium-1 large-1"]/span[@class="vote-button-legend"]/text()')
```

I can also use CSS Selectors to find the div class for the progress bar before extracting the value attribute

```
$('div progress.alert ')
```

---

From here I tried to use ItemLoaders to populate Items in Scrapy using the `add_xpath` and `add_css` methods:

```
l = ItemLoader(item=PropertiesItem(), response=response)

l.add_xpath('votes', '//div[@class="cell small-1 medium-1 large-1"]/span[@class="vote-button-legend"]/text()')

l.add_css('votes', 'div.cell.small-1.medium-1.large-1 span.vote-button-legend ::attr[value]')
```

When running my spider to check for the resulting items it doesn't appear in the console and when  I try to see if the output appears using a log it returns an empty list:

```
self.log("voteCount: %s" % response.css('div.cell.small-1.medium-1.large-1 span.vote-button-legend ::attr[value]').extract())

self.log("value: %s" % response.xpath('//div[@class="cell small-1 medium-1 large-1"]/span[@class="vote-button-legend"]/text()').extract())
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Post the HTML code as [code instead of an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: There are no obvious errors in any of your selectors. can you post the url?

Comment: This is the [URL](https://www.fragrantica.com/perfume/Xerjoff/Mefisto-Gentiluomo-52432.html) I'm using to scrape

Comment: 1. You should [edit] your question to include any new information, such as the url. 2. make sure you use the @IgorV symbol and username of the person you are addressing so they know that you have responded. 3. The elements you are trying to access are loaded dynamically 4. the website is protected by cloudflare.     ---- Your best option is probably to use a browser automation service like playwright or selenium to get the info